# id not auto incremented and duplicate records

Tags: mysql

This is my table `tb_currency_minimum_amount` 
[image]

When I am inserting a record using

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tb_currency_minimum_amount ( id, currency_id, payment_method, minimum_amount) VALUES (NULL, 1, 16, 0.02)
```

again and again it creates a new entry

**rows with id 32,33,34 are same**

It i assigning it id 32 not 27 and ignoring duplicates

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsqwW.png):[image]

Comment: :fyi in mysql auto increment id work as  +1 with last id ..have you been deleted records after 27 meanwhile you are working

Comment: I have not deleted rows @AnkitAgrawal

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column is to ensure unique identifiers for the rows in the table.

It is just an implementation detail that it uses consecutive integer values. It is not a requirement for these values to be consecutive. Your code must not rely on the values being consecutive.

The value of the `AUTO_INCREMENT` is increased by each `INSERT` statement when a value for that column is not provided, no matter if the updated value is used (the query creates a new row) or not (it fails because of a duplicate key constraint or it updates an existing row because of `ON DUPLICATE KEY`).

Comment: so what is the possible solution @axiac

Comment: In order to find a solution you have to clearly define the problem. I cannot see any problem in the question. The rows with IDs 32, 33 and 34 are similar because you ran the query 3 times. Apart from the PK, is there any `UNIQUE` index on the table?

Comment: these currency_id, payment_method,minimum_amount can not be unique as per the problem statement @axiac

Answer (score 0):

Auto increment is count every record with +1. But it does not check of other columns are unique or duplicates. 
In your id column which is auto increment I do not see any duplicates.

Could you elaborate your purpose what you trying to archive.

Comment: rows with id 32,33,34 are same @Noob

Comment: @art12345 you mean the colomn currency_id ? If you mean this it is right that it has the same id since there are no restrictions regarding duplicates in row. You can solve this to change to unique colomn.

Answer (score -1):

> It is adding assigning it id 32 not 27 and ignoring duplicates

If i understand your question correctly, you should use the **SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement.**

The SELECT DISTINCT statement is used to return only distinct (different) values.

Inside a table, a column often contains many duplicate values; and sometimes you only want to list the different (distinct) values.

The SELECT DISTINCT statement is used to return only distinct (different) values.

Comment: But i am inserting not fetching records @Lea Krause